# How to Enumerate All Document Set File Properties Using the SharePoint JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-jsom, document-set

The following code successfully loops over all my files in a particular Document Library and outputs the name of each file. However, there are additional properties  (custom properties/columns that are not part of the Document content type) that I need to enumerate. `get_item()` is not a valid method on the `SP.File` type, so I can't just pass in the property name that I'm looking for. I suspect I'll need to pass an `Include` argument to the `.load()` method, but I've been unsuccessful with that as it errors out telling me that the property names I've included don't exist.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Load the required SharePoint libraries.
    $(function () {
      var ctx = null;
      var collListItem = null;

      // Function to retrieve a query string value.
      // For production purposes you may want to use
      // a library to handle the query string.
      function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
        var params =
          document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&amp;");
        var strParams = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
          var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
          if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
        }
      }

      // Get the URI decoded URLs.
      hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));

      // The js files are in a URL in the form: web_url/_layouts/15/resource_file
      var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

      // Load the js files and continue to the execOperation function.
      $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function () {
          $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", mainFunction);
        }
      );

      var siteUrl = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/theSite";
      var docSetUrl = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/theSite/docLibraryName/docSetName";
      var ctx = null;
      var files = null;

      function mainFunction() {
        getFiles(docSetUrl);
      }

      function getFiles(folderUrl) {
        ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        files = ctx.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl).get_files();
        ctx.load(files);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(success, error);
      }

      function success() {
        console.log("success");
        for (var i = 0; i < files.get_count(); i++) {
          var file = files.get_item(i);
          console.log(file.get_name());
        }
      }

      function error(sender, args) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(args.get_message());
      }

    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in the [ListItemAllFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj168839(v=office.15)) property.

Copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16955986/5451962):

```
using (ClientContext spClientContext = new ClientContext("http://whatever"))
{
    var rootweb = spClientContext.Web;

    FolderCollection folderCollection =
        rootweb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/Shared Documents/test2").Folders;

    // Don't just load the folder collection, but the property on each folder too
    spClientContext.Load(folderCollection, fs => fs.Include(f => f.ListItemAllFields));

    // Actually fetch the data
    spClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (Folder folder in folderCollection)
    {
        // This property is now populated
        var item = folder.ListItemAllFields;

        // This is where the dates you want are stored
        var created = (DateTime)item["Created"];
        var modified = (DateTime)item["Modified"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> I suspect I'll need to pass an Include argument to the .load() method

that's right, to retrieve [`ListItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245356(v%3Doffice.15)) properties associated with a [`File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246089(v%3Doffice.15)) you need to specify the following expression `'Include(ListItemAllFields)'` via [`SP.ClientContext.load` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/dn168903%28v%3Doffice.15%29), for example:

```
ctx.load(files,'Include(ListItemAllFields)');
```

**Example**

```
function getFiles(folderUrl) {
   var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
   var files = ctx.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl).get_files();
   ctx.load(files,'Include(Name,ListItemAllFields)');
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(()=>{

      files.get_data().forEach(file =>{

         console.log(file.get_name()); //print file name
         console.log(file.get_listItemAllFields().get_fieldValues()); //print list item properties

      })

   },logError);
}


function logError(sender, args) {
   console.log(args.get_message());
}
```